# 2 Google Maps on one subpage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with Google Maps, I want to add two Google maps on one subpage, but there is an error-by clicking the marker on one map, takes place on the second map. Information on place can be seen only on a one map.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Maps</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google_maps.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
   <div id="map1" style="width: 600px; height: 360px;"></div>
   <div id="map2" style="width: 600px; height: 360px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var markerone = [
         [0, 51.504827, -0.07862599999998565, 'City hall of London', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        ]
var markertwo = [
         [0, 54.34879, 18.65256899999997, 'City hall of Gdańsk', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        ]
var markerMemo = null;
var infowindow = null;
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
maxWidth: 230
});
var map;

function initialize() {
    var myOptionsMap1 = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.50489356890002,-0.07370204693610383),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        navigationControl: true,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        rotateControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), myOptionsMap1);
        for(var i in markerone) {
        infowindow = '<div class="widows-map"><strong>' + markerone[i][3] + '</strong><p>';
                    if (markerone[i][6] && !markerone[i][7]) {
                        infowindow += markerone[i][6] + '</p>';
                    }
                    if (markerone[i][6] && markerone[i][7]) {
                        infowindow += '<a href="' + markerone[i][7] + '">' + markerone[i][6] + '</a></p>';
                    }
                    if (markerone[i][8]) {
                        infowindow += markerone[i][8] + '<br />';
                    }   
                    if (markerone[i][9]) {
                        infowindow += '<a href="http://maps.google.pl/maps?daddr=' + markerone[i][1] + ', ' + markerone[i][2] + '&hl=pl&ie=UTF8&z=' + map.getZoom() + '">How to go</a>';
                    }
                    '</div>'
            if (markerone[i][4]) {
                var markerOption =
                {
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerone[i][1], markerone[i][2]),
                    title: markerone[i][3],
                    html: infowindow,
                    icon: document.getElementById('link').href + markerone[i][4],
                    shadow: markerone[i][5]
                }
            } else {
                var markerOption =
                {
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerone[i][1], markerone[i][2]),
                    title: markerone[i][3],
                    html: infowindow
                }
            }
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOption);
        if (infowindow) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function ()
        {
            info.setContent(this.html);
            info.open(map, this);
        });
        }   else {
            infowindow = '';
        }
        if (i==0 && infowindow) {markerMemo = marker;}
    }
    if (markerMemo) google.maps.event.trigger(markerMemo, "click");

    var myOptionsMap2 = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.3488118865322,18.65266287731549),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        navigationControl: true,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        rotateControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), myOptionsMap2);
        for(var i in markertwo) {
        infowindow = '<div class="widows-map"><strong>' + markertwo[i][3] + '</strong><p>';
                    if (markertwo[i][6] && !markertwo[i][7]) {
                        infowindow += markertwo[i][6] + '</p>';
                    }
                    if (markertwo[i][6] && markertwo[i][7]) {
                        infowindow += '<a href="' + markertwo[i][7] + '">' + markertwo[i][6] + '</a></p>';
                    }
                    if (markertwo[i][8]) {
                        infowindow += markertwo[i][8] + '<br />';
                    }   
                    if (markertwo[i][9]) {
                        infowindow += '<a href="http://maps.google.pl/maps?daddr=' + markertwo[i][1] + ', ' + markertwo[i][2] + '&hl=pl&ie=UTF8&z=' + map.getZoom() + '">How to go</a>';
                    }
                    '</div>'
            if (markertwo[i][4]) {
                var markerOption =
                {
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markertwo[i][1], markertwo[i][2]),
                    title: markertwo[i][3],
                    html: infowindow,
                    icon: document.getElementById('link').href + markertwo[i][4],
                    shadow: markertwo[i][5]
                }
            } else {
                var markerOption =
                {
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markertwo[i][1], markertwo[i][2]),
                    title: markertwo[i][3],
                    html: infowindow
                }
            }
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOption);
        if (infowindow) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function ()
        {
            info.setContent(this.html);
            info.open(map, this);
        });
        }   else {
            infowindow = '';
        }
        if (i==0 && infowindow) {markerMemo = marker;}
    }
    if (markerMemo) google.maps.event.trigger(markerMemo, "click");
}
```

Comment: You only have one `map` variable.  If you have two maps, there should be two unique map variables.

Comment: I ask for more information

Answer (score 0):

You only have one map variable.  For two unique maps you need two map variables.  Just like if you want two unique infowindows (one on each map) you need two unique infowindow variables (and two unique marker variables).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvnt97kz/)

Working code snippet:

```js
var markerone = [
  [0, 51.504827, -0.07862599999998565, 'City hall of London', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
]
var markertwo = [
  [0, 54.34879, 18.65256899999997, 'City hall of Gdańsk', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
]
var markerMemo = null;
var infowindow = null;
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 230
});
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myOptionsMap1 = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.50489356890002, -0.07370204693610383),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    navigationControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    rotateControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
    },
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), myOptionsMap1);
  for (var i in markerone) {
    infowindow = '<div class="widows-map"><strong>' + markerone[i][3] + '</strong><p>';
    if (markerone[i][6] && !markerone[i][7]) {
      infowindow += markerone[i][6] + '</p>';
    }
    if (markerone[i][6] && markerone[i][7]) {
      infowindow += '<a href="' + markerone[i][7] + '">' + markerone[i][6] + '</a></p>';
    }
    if (markerone[i][8]) {
      infowindow += markerone[i][8] + '<br />';
    }
    if (markerone[i][9]) {
      infowindow += '<a href="http://maps.google.pl/maps?daddr=' + markerone[i][1] + ', ' + markerone[i][2] + '&hl=pl&ie=UTF8&z=' + map.getZoom() + '">How to go</a>';
    }
    '</div>'
    if (markerone[i][4]) {
      var markerOption = {
        map: map1,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerone[i][1], markerone[i][2]),
        title: markerone[i][3],
        html: infowindow,
        icon: document.getElementById('link').href + markerone[i][4],
        shadow: markerone[i][5]
      }
    } else {
      var markerOption = {
        map: map1,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerone[i][1], markerone[i][2]),
        title: markerone[i][3],
        html: infowindow
      }
    }
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOption);
    if (infowindow) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function() {
        info.setContent(this.html);
        info.open(map1, this);
      });
    } else {
      infowindow = '';
    }
    if (i == 0 && infowindow) {
      markerMemo = marker1;
    }
  }
  if (markerMemo) google.maps.event.trigger(markerMemo, "click");

  var myOptionsMap2 = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.3488118865322, 18.65266287731549),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    navigationControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    rotateControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
    },
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), myOptionsMap2);
  for (var i in markertwo) {
    infowindow = '<div class="widows-map"><strong>' + markertwo[i][3] + '</strong><p>';
    if (markertwo[i][6] && !markertwo[i][7]) {
      infowindow += markertwo[i][6] + '</p>';
    }
    if (markertwo[i][6] && markertwo[i][7]) {
      infowindow += '<a href="' + markertwo[i][7] + '">' + markertwo[i][6] + '</a></p>';
    }
    if (markertwo[i][8]) {
      infowindow += markertwo[i][8] + '<br />';
    }
    if (markertwo[i][9]) {
      infowindow += '<a href="http://maps.google.pl/maps?daddr=' + markertwo[i][1] + ', ' + markertwo[i][2] + '&hl=pl&ie=UTF8&z=' + map.getZoom() + '">How to go</a>';
    }
    '</div>'
    if (markertwo[i][4]) {
      var markerOption = {
        map: map2,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markertwo[i][1], markertwo[i][2]),
        title: markertwo[i][3],
        html: infowindow,
        icon: document.getElementById('link').href + markertwo[i][4],
        shadow: markertwo[i][5]
      }
    } else {
      var markerOption = {
        map: map2,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markertwo[i][1], markertwo[i][2]),
        title: markertwo[i][3],
        html: infowindow
      }
    }
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOption);
    if (infowindow) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function() {
        info.setContent(this.html);
        info.open(map2, this);
      });
    } else {
      infowindow = '';
    }
    if (i == 0 && infowindow) {
      markerMemo = marker;
    }
  }
  if (markerMemo) google.maps.event.trigger(markerMemo, "click");
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map1" style="width: 600px; height: 360px;"></div>
<div id="map2" style="width: 600px; height: 360px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question if I will follow markerone[i][9] and markertwo[i][9] as (true) - not show me (How to go) link it and the map does not work as it should

Comment: What does that mean?  Seems like that should be another _question_, not a comment.

Comment: One map is visible but there is no marker, and the second map does not displays at all

Comment: I see two markers and two maps in the code snippet and the fiddle.  What are you looking at?